# What is the proper way to do conversion on pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I got this code:

```
int sockfd, clilen;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;

// ...
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

When compiling, the error is:

> Invalid arguments. Candidates are: int accept(int, sockaddr *,
>   unsigned int *)

So, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Seems like C (or C++)

Comment: It asks for `unsigned int *`, you gave it `int *`, for the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I thought those two types can convert to each other.

Comment: actually the third parameter to `accept()`, per the man page, is expecting something similar to the following: `socklen_t *addrlen`  Suggest correcting the declaration for `clilen` to be: `socklen_t clilen;`

Comment: strongly suggest reading/understanding the man pages for those system functions that are called in your code